# Uncaught TypeError: datapoints.data.map is not a function at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

Tags: xmlhttprequest, typeerror

**Can anyone help me? I'm really bad at programming**

Error :Uncaught TypeError: datapoints.data.map is not a function at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange

---

```
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = '//url//';

xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
    const datapoints = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    //console.log(datapoints);
    const labelsboy = datapoints.data.map(function(item){
      return item.boy;
    });
    console.log(labelsboy);
  }
}
```

---

### file JSON API

{
"status": true,
"row": 2,
"data": {
"boy": 10,
"girl": 15
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is an array function but `datapoints.data` is an object. It seems like you are just trying to get one value from the object so you can just access it directly.

```
const labelsboy = datapoints.data.boy;
console.log(labelsboy);
```